# Selecting all empty <td> with specific class and removing the parent <tr> via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very large HTML table with many rows. The rows are filed in by variables set in javascript from a response from my database. If the database responds with " " the variable is set to " ". I would like to find this and remove an entire parent row if true in JavaScript.

I have tried the below code but I don't think I am selecting the correct cell. I marked all of the rows with the 'row' class and the cell that may be empty with the 'emptytd' class in an effort to make it easier to select. Thanks in advance!

```
                var something =  "<tr class='row'>" +
                                 "<th>AA03</th>" +
                                 "<td>" + aa03TrainTaskNm + "</td>" +
                                 "<td class='emptytd'>" + aa03DueDt + "</td></tr>";

$('#something').html(somthing);
$('#myModal').modal("show");
$('td.emptytd:[value=" "]').parents('tr.row').hide();
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Also in `$('#something').html(somthing);` you select an element with the ID of `something` but you don't have one in your code example, and then you use the variable `somthing` which doesn't exist (but `something` does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through them and check their content like so:

```
   $("td.emptytd").each(function(){
        if($(this).html() === "") $(this).parent().remove();
    })
```

Comment: So that successfully listed empty in the console as intended but how would I delete the parent row inside of the if statement?

Comment: sorry left the `console.log` by mistake :D It's supposed to be `remove()`

Comment: That selects the specific cell that is empty and removes just that cell. I would like to remove the parent table row.    


$("td.emptytd").each(function(){
          if($(this).html() === " ") $("tr.row").remove();
            })

Comment: to get the parent `tr` use `$(this).parent().remove()`

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all the offending rows at once, you could do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(el){
  if(el.innerHTML == " "){ 
    const row = el.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }
});
```

Note that even one "empty" cell in a row will trigger the removal of the entire row. And if the contents of a the cell are anything but a single spacebar character, nothing will happen. (If you want to handle other whitespace characters, you can use "/\s+/" to find any string of 1 or more whitespace characters.)